# Excel VBA .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Making a userform to add data to a database in VBA. What i'm wanting to do is pretty simple; to select the last filled row, and skip to the next empty cell in the row below.

Screenshot added with the problem highlighted.

[image]

Question is quite simple, what am I doing wrong, and how would it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.End(...` has nothing to reference to. If you wanted to add a linebreak, do so by writing:

```
Irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row
```

Watch the `_` with a space before it at the end of the first line.
This will connect the two lines, forming one valid statement.

Alternatively, just write the two lines as one:

```
Irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row
```

Comment: I'm glad to help - feel free to mark this question as answered then.